# Python concurrent.futures : sharing the same queue between multiple ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing

Is it possible for two ThreadPoolExecutor to share the same queue ?

In this example, I have two functions that process elements slightly differently. The first one needs 4 threads, the second only 2. How to implement the second function do_some_stuff_2() so that it processes the remaining elements in the queue ?

I'm quite new to concurrent and parallel programming, sorry if it seems dumb.

```
# elements to process
things_to_process = [element1, element2 ...]

# functions that will process the elements
def do_some_stuff_1(x):
    """
    I need 4 threads, please
    """
    'do some stuff'

def do_some_stuff_2(x):
    """
    I need only 2 threads, please
    """
    'do some different stuff'


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    future_to_element = {executor.submit(do_some_stuff, element): element for element in things_to_process}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_element):
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('{} generated an exception: {}'.format(element, exc))
```